# When I print the attributes of the XCUIApplication(), what does the value of the traits key represent?

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

Example output from dumping the XCUIApplication()

```
Application, pid: 34372, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}, label: 'MyApp'
Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}
  Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}
    Other, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {320.0, 568.0}}
      NavigationBar, **traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 20.0}, {320.0, 44.0}}, identifier: 'SillyDashboardView'
```

in the output above, what does `traits: 8589934592` represent? 
Reviewing the XCUIApplication object doesn't help, nor can I find any documentation from Apple. It would be useful to know what these values represent.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility/accessibility_traits gives the 'official' list of traits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitytraits), **UIAccessibilityTraits** is:

> A mask that contains the OR combination of the accessibility traits that best characterize an accessibility element.

What is actually **[UIAccessibilityTraits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitytraits)**? Just another alias for 64-bit integer value which means that there are 64 different traits a view can have each bit representing one trait. Looking at the [list of all possible traits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility/accessibility_traits), you can see that there are about 17 known tratis (as Oletha pointed out, there may be some unknown traits that Apple uses but they doesn't share with us).

If you print some of them, like this:

```
print(UIAccessibilityTraitNone) //Prints 0
print(UIAccessibilityTraitButton) //Prints 1
print(UIAccessibilityTraitLink) //Prints 2
print(UIAccessibilityTraitImage) //Prints 4
//...
```

You can see that every trait is a value that is of some power of 2 (which in turn has only one bit set). So, `OR`-ing every particular trait gives you final number you see when you print out `XCUIApplication()`.

So, in your example, if you pick the one with number `35192962023424`, you have:

```
 35192962023424 or in binary:
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
                       ^              ^
```

Which means that there are two traits applied for this view. The one with value `35184372088832`, or in binary:

```
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
                       ^
```

and the one with value `8589934592`, or in binary:

```
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
                                      ^
```

Looking at the [*known*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility/accessibility_traits) traits for those two numbers, you can conclude that no known trait is given for those views.

**My guess** looking at the output is that `35184372088832` trait is `NavigationBars` trait, and `8589934592` is `Others` trait. Maybe, this is how you query [*navigationBars*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider/1501000-navigationbars) or [*otherElements*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider/1500979-otherelements).

Comment: this answer is best so far, but could be improved by linking to the actual traits list here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility/accessibility_traits

Comment: Oh, thanks :) Actually, I already inserted this link in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The traits number will be different based on which [accessibilityTraits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615202-accessibilitytraits) are set on the object. Some objects come with accessibility traits out of the box, and you can add or remove them as you please. These traits will mean different things to XCTest, e.g. the `.button` trait means the element will show up when you query for buttons, the `.selected` trait affects the value of `XCUIElement.isSelected`...

It's possible that this number is also affected by other properties that Apple don't share with us, but for the purposes of a UI test, you should only need to observe the value of accessibilityTraits.